# Alert field value in text field

Tags: jquery

I am having a text field for entering numbers. I want to alert the numbers which I enter into the text field.  My HTML is:

```
<input id="search_number" type="text" name="numbers" />
<button id="wmsearch">Search</button>
```

And JS is:

```
var sn = ($('#search_number').val());
$('#wmsearch').click(function(){
if(sn != 1234567890){
alert(sn);
}else
{
alert('equal');
}
});
```

It doesn't works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#wmsearch').click(function () {
    var sn = $('#search_number').val();
    if (sn != 1234567890) {
        alert(sn);
    } else {
        alert('equal');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the `val()` of `$('#search_number')` in the click event handler.

```
$('#wmsearch').click(function() {
    var sn = $('#search_number').val();

    if(sn != 1234567890) {
        alert(sn);
    } else {
        alert('equal');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('#wmsearch').click(function(){
    var sn = $('#search_number').val();//you don't need extra bracket here
    if(sn != 1234567890){
      alert(sn);
    }else
    {
       alert('equal');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the jQuery object to `#search_number` outside of the `click` event handler, but get the value inside of it. Doing this will save you one DOM call per click.

Also, don't forget to parse the string into an integer using `parseInt`.

```
var $search_number = $('#search_number');
$('#wmsearch').click(function(){
    var sn = parseInt($search_number.val(), 10);

    if(sn != 1234567890){
        alert(sn);
    } else {
        alert('equal');
    }
});
```

---

Having said that, you can simplify the script by using the [`?:` conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
var $search_number = $('#search_number');
$('#wmsearch').click(function(){
    var sn = parseInt($search_number.val(), 10);
    alert( (sn == 1234567890) ? "equal" : sn );
});
```

[See a live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ptsvd/)